# Projective roots of a homogeneous polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, projective-geometry

Suppose that $f(X,Y)\in\mathbb C[X,Y]$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$, then we can consider it as a function on $\mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$. It has at most $n+1$ projective roots (points of $\mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$), namely the "affine" roots (that are $n$) plus possibly the point at infinity.

Now consider the following two homogeneous polynomials in **three** variables (over $\mathbb C$):

$$F(X,Y,Z)=Z^m+Z^{m-1}F_1(X,Y)+\ldots+F_m$$
$$G(X,Y,Z)=Z^n+Z^{n-1}G_1(X,Y)+\ldots+G_n$$

where $F_i$ and $G_i$ are homogeneous of degree $i$. The resultant $R_{F,G}$ respect to the variable $Z$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $mn$, so it has at most $mn+1$ projective roots. I don't understand why, in some proofs of the Bezout theorem, authors say this fact leads to an absurd. It seems that $R_{F,G}$ can only have $mn$ projective roots but i don't understand the reason.

Comment: your inital statement is wrong. a homo poly of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots including infinity.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why. Consider
$F(X,Y)=F_0(Y)X^n+F_1(Y)X^{n-1}+\ldots+F_n(Y)$; I have at most $n$ solution of the type $(1:y)$ plus possibly $(0:1)$. Where is the mistake?

Comment: $(0 : 1)$ is a zero if and only if $F_n (Y) = 0$; but in that case, $F (X, Y)$ is divisible by $Y$, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I dont get the notation, but write, $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}y +\cdots$ then infinity is a solution iff $a_n=0$ so this takes away from the number of finite solutions.

Comment: @ZhenLin Lin $Y$ divides $F(X,Y)$ and...?

Comment: Oh yeah it is clear.

Comment: The zeros of $F(X,Y)$ taking the form $(1:Y)$ are in bijection with the zeros of the polynomial obtained by setting $X=1$ in $F(X,Y)$. If $(0:1)$ is a solution, then as Zhen Lin points out, $Y$ divides $F(X,Y)$> It follows that when you set $X=1$ to work in an affine chart, your polynomial will have degree less than $n$, so you can have at most $n-1$ roots of the form $(1:Y)$. This shows that the total number of roots is at most $n$ in any case.

Comment: Yeah many thanks. I'm sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Your first sentence is false for every $n\gt0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me answer by showing how a homogenous polynomial of degree $n$ in the projective line has $n$ solutions.

A typical such polynomial is

$$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}y+\cdots +a_0y^n$$

let us assume that $a_{m}\neq 0$ is the first nonzero coefficient
then the equation factors

$$a_m y^{n-m}(x-\beta_1 y) \cdots (x-\beta_m y)$$ 
now for $y=1$ we have the finite roots $[\beta_1:1], \ldots , [\beta_m:1]$

Now $y=0$ is a root only if $n-m\neq 0$ in which case this root occurs $n-m$ times so the total number of roots counting multiplicity is always 
$$m+(n-m)=n$$